# Malformed pom.xml exception Apache Maven

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, pom.xml

**Hello there.I have a JavaSpring MVC application. I am trying to use spring mvc with a mongodb database and apache maven.But I have a problem with the pom.xml file.This is my pom.xml file :**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmln.s="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>finartzProject</groupId>
<artifactId>FinartzProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
  
  <!-- spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  
  <!-- jstl -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- javax servlet -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 
  
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
   <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
       
       
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
           <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
           <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
       
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>never</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
       
      
     </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

**and I get this messages.**

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Malformed POM C:\Users\Suleyman\workspace\FinartzProject\pom.xml: Unknown attribute 'xmln.s' for tag 'project' (position: START_TAG seen ...apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">... @2:206)  @ C:\Users\Suleyman\workspace\FinartzProject\pom.xml, line 2, column 206
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project finartzProject:FinartzProject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Suleyman\workspace\FinartzProject\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Malformed POM C:\Users\Suleyman\workspace\FinartzProject\pom.xml: Unknown attribute 'xmln.s' for tag 'project' (position: START_TAG seen ...apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">... @2:206)  @ C:\Users\Suleyman\workspace\FinartzProject\pom.xml, line 2, column 206 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

Comment: replace `xmln.s` by `xmlns`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo,

`<project xmln.s`

Should be

`<project xmlns`

Comment: Oh god.Thank you so much,I am trying to solve this till morning.

Comment: It was written in your output log 'Unknown attribute 'xmln.s' for tag 'project'